# Координаты изображений

Tags: javascript

Кто-нибудь может сказать, почему код не работает?: 
https://jsfiddle.net/DarkMessiah/uba81cx9/5/

```
 mouseX = document.getElementById('mouse').offsetTop;
 mouseY = document.getElementById('mouse').offsetLeft;
 inputX = document.getElementById('droppable-input').offsetTop;
 inputY = document.getElementById('droppable-input').offsetLeft;
function check() {
 if ((mouseX == inputX) && (mouseY == inputY)) {
   alert('Правильно');
 }
}
```

mouse и droppable-input - картинки
Выдает ошибки: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null
и
Uncaught ReferenceError: mouseX is not defined (при выполнении функции)

Кто-нибудь знает, как исправить? Или как иначе можно сравнить положение двух картинок? (нужно знать пересекаются ли они или нет.)

Comment: `mouseX = inputX` - вот здесь идет не сравнение, а присваивание.

Comment: да, исправил, но ошибка идет раньше. здесь: 
 mouseX = document.getElementById('mouse').offsetTop;

Comment: У вас есть элемент на странице с `id=mouse`? К тому же, функция check переписывала переменную `mouseX`. После исправления ошибка остается?

Comment: В приведенном коде два элемента с id='mouse'. Может, в этом дело.

Comment: Да, элемент есть (по ссылке есть полный код). Теперь при выполнении функции добавляется вторая ошибка: Uncaught ReferenceError: mouseX is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null` означает, что вызов
`document.getElementById('mouse')` вернул `null`, то есть не нашел элемент с именем `mouse` и с этого `null` вы пытаетесь получить свойство `offsetTop`, что сделать невозможно.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: mouseX is not defined` - не определена переменная с именем `mouseX`. Вы ее объявили? Это делается при помощи ключевого слова `var`.

Что касатся обнаружения пересечения двух прямоугольников (избражений), то надо построить уравнения отрезков сторон и проверять эти отрезки на пересечения друг с другом